# Keyboard and mouse doesn't function from the booting stage onward. Using 18.04 on Dell Inspirion Laptop

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard, mouse, touchpad

After updating Ubuntu instead of restarting my laptop I edited the GRUB configuration file in `/etc/default/grub` and changed the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

To:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.direct i8042.dumbkbd"
```

After doing those changes I restarted the laptop. I can make only a single click after that it stops working and when I press any key on the keyboard keeps pressing the <kbd>`</kbd> key and will get stuck. This only happens on the laptop's keyboard and touchpad. When I connect an external keyboard or mouse it works just fine.

I tried changing the GRUB file back to how it was before but the problem still persists. I am completely inexperienced with the GRUB settings. I am using version 18.04.3 LTS.